# Importing multiple versions of Powershell Modules loads them all?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

Importing multiple versions of modules (this is PS7):

```
Import-Module -Name MyModule -RequiredVersion 1.0.28
Import-Module -Name MyModule -RequiredVersion 1.0.29
```

Will load both versions into your session:

```
Get-Module -Name MyModule
```

Outputs:

```
ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name
---------- -------    ---------- ---- 
Script     1.0.28                MyModule
Script     1.0.29                MyModule
```

This becomes quite confusing when you're trying to write CI/CD scripts, because someone may have multiple versions loaded locally. In my case I want to ensure a specific version is loaded before continuing.

Which version does PS actually use in this scenario? Is it the last loaded rather than the highest version?

Is there an easy way to ensure a specific version is being used, short of looping over all other versions and removing them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Which version does PS actually use in this scenario?

**The *most recently imported* version takes precedence**, which the output of [`Get-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module) indicates in *reverse* order of precedence (as of PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.5); that is, **the *last* version listed in `Get-Module` output for a given module is the one in effect** (for commands of the same name).

For a given *command*, you can use [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) to see what module (version) it comes from.<sup>[1]</sup>

**Caveat**: The most recently imported version only takes precedence in the sense that it shadows *commands of the same name* from previously imported versions. Therefore, if a previously imported version has *additional* commands not defined (anymore) by the most recently imported version, they are still in effect.

---

> Is there an easy way to ensure a specific version is being used, short of looping over all other versions and removing them?

If you want to ensure that no other versions are loaded, use **`Remove-Module <name>`**, which **removes *all* versions of the module** with the given name from the session.

By contrast, **if you wanted to unload a *specific* version**, you'd pass a *fully qualified module name* to [`Remove-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/remove-module)'s `-FullyQualifiedName` parameter; e.g.:

```
Remove-Module -FullyQualifiedName @{ ModuleName = 'MyModule'; RequiredVersion = '1.0.28' }
```

Note the use of the `RequiredVersion` key to specify the *exact* version to unload; by contrast, using key `ModuleVersion` would unload the given version *and all higher ones*.

Also note:

- As noted in [Cpt.Whale's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67217491/45375):

  - **See caveats re auto-loading modules below**.
  - You can similarly use `-FullyQualifiedName` or `-RequiredVersion` with [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) for version-specific importing.
  - You can choose to import *selectively*, i.e. a *subset* of a given module's exports, using the `-Cmdlet`, `-Function`, `-Alias` and `-Variable` parameters.

    - Note: Using *any* of these parameters means that you must then explicitly specify *all* exports you want to import, across the relevant parameters; e.g., if you use `-Alias @()` in order to effectively *exclude* exported aliases from import, you must also use the `-Cmdlet` / `-Function` parameter to specify what cmdlets / functions you *do* want to import; however, you can use `-Cmdlet *` / `-Function *` to select them all.
- **Caveats re [auto-loading modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading)** - i.e. those placed in one of the directories listed in `$env:PSModulePath`,  as is *typical*:

  - If you have removed all versions of a module with `Remove-Module` but at least one version is auto-loading, using any of its exported commands later triggers its (re)import, with all its exports getting imported.
  - Similarly, if you have imported a specific version of a module and a (different) version of the same module is (also) auto-loading, using an exported command that is *exclusive to the latter* triggers the latter's auto-loading, and thereby *implicitly shadows those exports that have the same name from the originally imported, specific version*
  - The risk of that happening increases if you have used `-Cmdlet`, `-Function`, `-Alias` and `-Variable` for *selective* importing of the originally imported, specific version, because then use of any of the *non-imported* exports that are also present in the auto-loading version trigger auto-loading of the latter.
  - A simple example: Say you manually import version `1.0` of module `Foo` in order to load the `Get-Foo` cmdlet (`Import-Module Foo -RequiredVersion 1.0`). However, the auto-loading version of `Foo` is version `2.0`, and also has a `Set-Foo` command. When you call `Set-Foo` later, version `2.0` is *implicitly* (automatically) imported, and *its* `Get-Foo` implementation now shadows the one from the originally imported `1.0` version of `Foo`.

---

<sup>[1] Note that you can even get a reference to a currently *shadowed* command by requesting it via its specific module version using the `-FullyQualifiedModule` parameter (e.g.

`Get-Command Get-Foo -FullyQualifiedModule @{ ModuleName='Foo'; RequiredVersion='1.0.28' }`

), which you can then invoke with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-). However, due to the bug detailed in [GitHub issue #15298](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15298), present as of PowerShell Core 7.2.0-preview.5, this only works if the targeted module version was *explicitly imported* first (e.g., `Import-Module Foo -RequiredVersion 1.0.28`).</sup>

Comment: @Boologne, please see my update (start with "Also note:").

Comment: very thorough answer - I was having fun trying to duel run versions 4 and 5 of Pester - I need 4 for PSKoans but for other learning I'm doing I need 5 - but using this answer I've add a function to my Profile to dynamically import the correct Pester depending on what I'm working on - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Adding more details that I've had trouble with to mklement0's great answer:

- `Get-Module` returns a list of `ExportedFunctions`,`ExportedCmdlets`, and `ExportedCommands` for each loaded module version. Perfect!
- Be wary of nested modules! Powershell will separate information for the named module, and list any secondary modules under the `NestedModules` property of the one you asked for.
- You can specify which commands and module version when you `import-module`, which can let you manage your running environment better than just importing the entire module at once.

Examples:

```
# Here I have two versions loaded, but only one has any exported cmdlets:
Get-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement | Format-List Version,ExportedFunctions,ExportedCmdlets,ExportedCommands,NestedModules

Version           : 2.0.4
ExportedFunctions : {[Connect-ExchangeOnline, Connect-ExchangeOnline], …}
ExportedCmdlets   : {[Get-EXOCasMailbox, Get-EXOCasMailbox], …}
ExportedCommands  : {[Get-EXOCasMailbox, Get-EXOCasMailbox], …}
NestedModules     : {Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RestApiClient,
                    Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellGalleryModule}

Version           : 2.0.5
ExportedFunctions : {[Connect-ExchangeOnline, Connect-ExchangeOnline], …}
ExportedCmdlets   : {}
ExportedCommands  : {[Connect-ExchangeOnline, Connect-ExchangeOnline], …}
NestedModules     : {}

# I can see function Connect-ExchangeOnline was loaded twice, so to see which version is active:
Get-Command Connect-ExchangeOnline 

CommandType : Function
Name        : Connect-ExchangeOnline
Version     : 2.0.5
Source      : ExchangeOnlineManagement

# I use this to see current loaded assemblies, and module version should be in the path
[appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |
    Where { $_.Modules.FullyQualifiedName.contains('ExchangeOnlineManagement') } |
    Select -ExpandProperty Modules |
    Format-List Name,Assembly,FullyQualifiedName

Name               : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.AdminApiProvider.dll
Assembly           : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.AdminApiProvider, Version=17.0.0.0
FullyQualifiedName : \path\to\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\2.0.4\netCore\Microsoft.Exch 
                     ange.Management.AdminApiProvider.dll

Name               : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellGalleryModule.dll
Assembly           : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ExoPowershellGalleryModule, Version=17.0.0.0
FullyQualifiedName : \path\to\Modules\ExchangeOnlineManagement\2.0.4\netCore\Microsoft.Exch 
                     ange.Management.ExoPowershellGalleryModule.dll
```